# Create extra columns in pandas time-indexed DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, pandas, dataframe

I currenty have a Datetime-Indexed dataframe with three columns:

```
                     Glucosa   Insulina  Carbs
Hour
2018-05-16 06:43:00    156.0       7.0   65.0
2018-05-16 07:43:00    170.0       0.0   65.0
2018-05-16 08:45:00    185.0       2.0    0.0
2018-05-16 09:45:00    150.0       0.0    0.0
2018-05-16 10:45:00     80.0       0.0    0.0
     ...
```

I would like to create three extra columns that hold the values indexed one hour from the current index to end up with something like this:

```
                     Glucosa   Insulina  Carbs  Glucosa1  Insulina1  Carbs1
Hour
2018-05-16 06:43:00    156.0       7.0   65.0      170.0        0.0   65.0
2018-05-16 07:43:00    170.0       0.0   65.0      185.0        2.0    0.0
2018-05-16 08:45:00    185.0       2.0    0.0      150.0        0.0    0.0
2018-05-16 09:45:00    150.0       0.0    0.0       80.0        0.0    0.0
2018-05-16 10:45:00     80.0       0.0    0.0       ...         ...    ...
     ...
```

I have already defined a function that creates a dataframe with the columns 'Glucosa1',  'Insulina1',  'Carbs1' but it is very poorly performing and I would like to make it run faster.

I profile the time used by different functions on my code using the following:

```
start = time.time()
  # foo() 
end = time.time()
print(f' Time required to execute foo() : {end - start}')
```

This outputs a time of 8.331165 seconds (on average) for the function nn_format_df() compared to similar functions (which iterate over the rows of the dataframe) wicht output 0.366158 seconds .

After creating a new dataframe calling my function on the original I merge them to get the desired dataframe.

```
df2 = nn_format_df(df)
df = df.join([df2])
```

The function:

```
def nn_format_df( df : pd.core.frame.DataFrame ) -> pd.core.frame.DataFrame:

  _indices   : pd.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex = [ idx for idx in df.index ]
  indices    = _indices[:-60]
  _df        : pd.core.frame.DataFrame = df.copy()
  _df1       : pd.core.frame.DataFrame
  _glc1      : pd.core.series.Series   = pd.Series(pd.np.nan, index=_indices)
  _insu1     : pd.core.series.Series   = pd.Series(pd.np.nan, index=_indices)
  _carbs1    : pd.core.series.Series   = pd.Series(pd.np.nan, index=_indices)

  aux        : pd._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
  aux1       : pd._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
  one        : datetime.timedelta = datetime.timedelta(hours=1) 

  for idx in indices:
    aux  = _df.ix[ idx, : ].name
    aux1 = aux + one
    _glc1[   idx ]  = _df.ix[ aux1, 'Glucosa' ]
    _insu1[  idx ]  = _df.ix[ aux1, 'Insulina' ]
    _carbs1[ idx ]  = _df.ix[ aux1, 'Carbs' ]

  _df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Glucosa1': _glc1,\
                       'Insulina1': _insu1,\
                          'Carbs1': _carbs1
                      }, index=_indices)

  return _df1
```

To sum it up:

- I would appreciate any comments on how to improve the function so that it doesn't take so long.
- A better, more Pythonic or pandas-y way of getting the desired dataframe is welcome. I am new to pandas and I understand my implementation of the function is a completely naïve approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this very quickly with `.shift`, which shifts an entire `DataFrame`. Just use `pd.concat` to combine them together; the `axis=1` argument specifies that you want to append new columns instead of rows.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat([df, df.shift(-1).rename(columns=dict((elem, elem+'1') for elem in df.columns))], axis=1)
```

The above code gives you the following output:

```
                     Glucosa  Insulina  Carbs  Glucosa1  Insulina1  Carbs1
Hour                                                                      
2018-05-16 06:43:00    156.0       7.0   65.0     170.0        0.0    65.0
2018-05-16 07:43:00    170.0       0.0   65.0     185.0        2.0     0.0
2018-05-16 08:45:00    185.0       2.0    0.0     150.0        0.0     0.0
2018-05-16 09:45:00    150.0       0.0    0.0      80.0        0.0     0.0
2018-05-16 10:45:00     80.0       0.0    0.0       NaN        NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the kind of performance I wanted to achieve. Didn't know about the shift method. So if instead of shift(-1) I used shift(-2) I would get the entries two rows downwards, etc?

Comment: @MagannaDev correct. And you can use positive integers to shift them in the other direction. The documentation is here: [`pandas.DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

Comment: That's very useful for the project I'm currently working on. Thank you @ALollz